# Testing pythagorean triples: $333,444,555$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

In [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Elementary_properties_of_primitive_Pythagorean_triples) page there is a necessary and sufficient test given for testing Pythagorean triples:

> A simpler, more powerful test is, (by naming the even leg a): $(c − a)$ and $\large\frac{(c − b)}{2}$ are both perfect squares. This is both
>   necessary and sufficient for the triple to be a PT.

Using this here,we can write $a = 444,b=333,c=555$,which means $111$ and $\frac{222}{2}=111$ must be perfect squares but it is not.Hence,that will not work.

**Is there any necessary and sufficient condition that will work for every and any (other than summing up the squares and checking for perfect squares?**

**NOTE:** $333,444,555$ are Pythagorean triples as $3\times111,4\times111,5\times111$ for $3,4,5$ is a Pythagorean triple.

Comment: Read the page you linked to again. Hint: Check the definition of a *primitive* Pythagorean triple.

Comment: "This is both necessary and sufficient for the triple to be a PT[citation needed], but the PT may be derivative. If any two sides of a PT are relatively prime, it is a PPT." Wikipedia, which in this case probably is wrong (see the citation needed) says that it is true for all Pythagorean triples.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a mistake in the phrasing of the condition.

Every Pythagorean triple is of the form

$$ a = 2k mn \qquad b = k(m^2 - n^2) \qquad c = k(m^2 + n^2) $$

which means that

$$ c - a = k(m^2 + n^2 - 2mn) = k (m-n)^2 \qquad \frac{c-b}{2} = k n^2 $$

So the correct statement is that

> Let $d$ be the greatest common divisor of $c-a$ and $(c-b)/2$. Then a necessary and sufficient condition for $(a,b,c)$ to be a Pythagorean triple is that $(c-a)/d$ and $(c-b)/(2d)$ are both perfect squares.

Comment: Though honestly, I don't think this condition, which requires finding the GCD and checking whether a number is a perfect square, is any *easier* than the "square-and-sum" method of checking.

Answer (score 0):

The page is not correct in stating that this relation is necessary for a Pythagorean triple, as you have shown.  For a non-primitive triple $c-a$ and $\frac{c-b}{2}$ can share a factor, $111$ in your case.  The relation is sufficient, but it will yield some non-primitive triples, such as $27,36,45$, where $c-a=9, \frac{c-b}{2}=9$.  If $c-a$ and $\frac{c-b}{2}$ do not share a factor and are not squares, it is not a PT.

Answer (score 0):

There is more simpler way to solve (333, 444, 555) for being a triple. It obviously is a multiple of primitive triple, so extract out its common factor: 111(3,4,5); forget about common factor, prove (3,4,5) is a primitive triple; let ( 3, 4, 5 ) be a triple representing in that order (x,y,z); k=z+y = 5+4 = 9; j= z-y= 5-4= 1; j*k =x^2. So product of 9 and 1 is 9 = 3^2.So x =3. That is evidently the case. So (333, 444, 555) is a Pythagorean triple.

Answer (score -1):

Let 333, 444, and 555 are x,y,z of a Pythagorean triple to be tested.
Rule to remember: "a given triple is Pythagorean iff there are two integers (j,k; k>j) such that square root of their product is an integer (obviously x) where k = z+y and j=z-y"
In this example: k=555+444=999, j=555-444=111; j*k = 110889; (jk)^(0.5) = 333, which is an integer and hence x.
Test is proven.